# How to setup a GraphQL SataSource in JasperReport Server CP 7.5.0?

Tags: graphql, datasource, jasperserver, jaspersoft-studio

As the title suggests, I would like to use a GraphQL DataSource in my jasper report server to create reports with the RESTv2 services made available by the server itself. I can't find any documentation or tutorials of any kind on how to configure this GraphQL DataSource.

On jaspersoft.com there is only this written about the topic: "You can run GraphQL queries and join multiple data sources out-of-the-box in JasperReports Server as of 7.5, via the available AutoREST Connector for JDBC, without having to install any additional packages. We go through the setup and use cases to get you started!", then follows a video where however it is not explained how to configure everything.

Does anyone happen to use this type of DataSource in jasperReportServer?

Could you kindly list the steps to follow to configure it?

Thank you